# When NFS Client try to create a file on shared folder, operation not permitted occurs, both server and client are in containers

Tags: docker, nfs, container

I've googled a lot and found some similar cases. However, none of them works in my case. Not sure if it has something to do with Mac.

I will try to describe my question as clearly as possible.

- I use KIND to run a local Kubernetes cluster with 3 nodes. I mount a volume in the master node `/data/k8s` from my local MacOS `/tmp/k8s`
- I create a NFS Server on the master node, export `/data/k8s`
- I also install NFS on the slave node as NFS Client, and mount master node `/data/k8s` to my the slave node local `/data/k8s`

and here is the problem:

- Everything works well on master node, no problem.
- On slave node, I `CANNOT` create a regular file while I CAN create a folder
- On slave node, I `CAN` revise any files created on master node
- Any files created on master node would sync without problems on slave node.

and here is some information:

- The OS (Both master and slave are identical)

```
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="19.10 (Eoan Ermine)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
```

- mount information on master node (The space is initially mounted from host MacOS)

```
root@test2-control-plane:/data/k8s# mount | grep /data
grpcfuse on /data/k8s type fuse.grpcfuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,max_read=1048576)
```

- exports setting on master node

```
/data/k8s/ *(fsid=0,rw,sync,no_root_squash)
```

- etab information on master node

```
*(rw,sync,wdelay,hide,nocrossmnt,secure,no_root_squash,no_all_squash,no_subtree_check,secure_locks,acl,no_pnfs,fsid=0,anonuid=65534,anongid=65534,sec=sys,rw,secure,no_root_squash,no_all_squash)
```

- permission information on master node

```
root@test2-control-plane:/data/k8s# ls -al
total 24
drwxrwxrwx 7 root root  224 Dec 25 01:50 .
drwxrwxrwx 3 root root 4096 Dec 24 12:33 ..
```

- mount information on slave node

```
root@test2-worker:/data/k8s# mount | grep /data
172.18.0.4:/data/k8s on /data/k8s type nfs (rw,relatime,vers=3,rsize=262144,wsize=262144,namlen=255,hard,nolock,proto=tcp,timeo=600,retrans=2,sec=sys,mountaddr=172.18.0.4,mountvers=3,mountport=45257,mountproto=udp,local_lock=all,addr=172.18.0.4)
```

- permission information on slave node

```
root@test2-worker:/data/k8s# ls -al
total 24
drwxrwxrwx 8 root root  256 Dec 25 02:17 .
drwxrwxrwx 3 root root 4096 Dec 24 13:23 ..
```

- What I've tried:

  - I've checked SELinux

  ```
  root@test2-control-plane:/data/k8s# sestatus
  SELinux status:                 disabled
  ```

  - I've tried to add `all_squash` and add `anonuid` and `anongid` with a specific user, and I define the user with identical user_id and group_id on both master node and slave node. And then switch to the defined user on my slave node.
  - Have tried so many that I can't remember them all.

I know it may be a specific case. If anyone could help will be so so much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the exact same issue running K8s locally with Docker Desktop on:

- macOS Big Sur 11.1
- docker v20.10.5
- k8s v1.19.7

I was perplexed by the behavior and decided to swap the hostPath volume with an emptyDir just to see if there would be any difference without host system OS permissions to deal with. For some reason, it worked so I just built a workaround using the emptyDir and some lifeCycle hooks on the NFS server to load/save the files from/to the host system on container start/stop.

Here is the code: https://github.com/tonymichaelson/k8s-nfs-operation-not-permittied-workaround

It's super strange how the NFS server creates files on the hostPath volume but not its clients. However, since this is just for local dev I didn't want to spend a lot of time on this. Also, the solution in the cloud will never use hostPath.

Cheers,
Tony